# How to put a jquery inside a parial view that will only work in that partial view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for this since hours now, i have a view with a modal that pop on button click, inside this modal i have a partial view. And inside my partial view i have this

```
    <input type="text" /><input type="text" /><input type="text" /><input type="submit" disabled="true" />
```

and a jquery :

```
function doCheck() {
    var allFilled = true;
    $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            allFilled = false;
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('input[type=submit]').prop('disabled', !allFilled);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').keyup(doCheck).focusout(doCheck);
});
```

so when all the fields are complete the button is enabled, but it's not working well because on the page where i call the modal i have textboxes and they are empty, so the script is waiting for the empty boxes to be filled but i don't want that i want the script to work only on the partial view. If someone as a clue to that, hope my question is well asked.

Thanks !

Comment: Give the textboxes in the partial a class name (say `class="model-input"`) and use `$('.modal-input').each(function () { ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 $("#YourModalDivId :input[type=...]")
```

Comment: That work well ! I put my input inside a div and gave the div an id !

Answer (score 4):

Be more selective.  eg. Put a div around the content of the partial view with a unique ID (I'll call it SomeID) and then change your selectors to refer to `#SomeID input[type=text]` rather than just `input[type=text]`